# How to setup CORB

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

How can I construct this XQuery to run in a CORB job? The 2nd module to process each doc with a matching candidate URI is not working.

**URIS Module**

```
(:a module to select the candidate URIs to process:)
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare variable $target-collection := "/activity";  
declare variable $update-collection := "/activity/analytics-read-added"

let $uris := cts:uris( (),
                       (),
                       cts:and-query((          
                           cts:collection-query($target-collection),
                           cts:not-query(cts:collection-query($update-collection))
                        ))
)
return (count($uris), $uris)
```

**Process Module**

```
(:a module to process each doc with a matching candidate URI:)
declare variable $URI as xs:string external;

 xdmp:document-add-permission($URI,xdmp:permission("act-read-role","read")),

xdmp:document-add-collections($URI,$update-collection)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of small issues with your process module:

- the variable `$update-collection` declared in the URIS Module also needs to be declared in the Process Module, if you want to use it.
- The function to add permissions is misspelled. It is plural: [`xdmp:document-add-permissions()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-add-permissions)

Applying those changes to the Process module:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
(:a module to process each doc with a matching candidate URI:)
declare variable $URI as xs:string external;
declare variable $update-collection := "/activity/analytics-read-added";

 xdmp:document-add-permissions($URI, xdmp:permission("act-read-role","read")),
 xdmp:document-add-collections($URI, $update-collection)
```

If you need to troubleshoot and investigate why your Process Module isn't working, it is sometimes easiest to paste the content of the Process Module XQuery into Query Console, assign a value to the `$URI` variable, and execute in QConsole.

For example:

```
declare variable $URI as xs:string external := "/some/test/doc.xml";
```